# Do I need to compile my solution with VS2010 in order to benefit from .NET 4.0 new Code Access Security Policy?

Tags: .net, .net-4.0, .net-3.5

I currently develop an application in C# with framework .NET 3.5 SP1.

In my app, I have satellite assemblies which are not in the same folder as the exe, and that causes me some trouble with FullTrust, as explained [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/shawnfa/archive/2008/05/12/fulltrust-on-the-localintranet.aspx?CommentPosted=true).

In order to solve that problem, I wish to use .NET 4.0 whose Code Access Security Policy should allow my satellite assemblies to be FullyTrusted.

So my question is: is just installing the framework enough, or do I need to rebuild the solution with VS2010?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use anything in .net 4.0 you need to recompile the application to use the .net 4.0 runtime environment. 
Remember the .net runtime environments run side by side, so a 3.5 application will still use it's runtime environment (2.0) and not the newest one.